# Is there a CSS-only (no JavaScript) solution to fit variable content to a vertical grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a small issue with a [website](http://westerndesigndays.com/) I'm currently working on, that doesn't bother me too much, but would be nice to fix. We've designed the site (along with the rest of the advertising for this event) to be based on a strict square grid. Everything is working just fine, except for one little problem:

At the bottom of the page, we have a few paragraphs of body copy that are throwing off the page by a third of a grid square. (We have the line-height of the text to be a third of a grid square) Short of Javascript calculations, is there any way we can add some sort of "smart" padding to the bottom of these paragraphs to re-align the next elements to the grid?

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what the problem is. Could you add a screenshot which points out the problem?

Comment: Sure. [Here you go](http://cl.ly/3M2Z0W2P1I3k092L213L). Sorry it's confusing, I'm not so great at writing clearly.

Comment: That depends on how smart you want it?

Comment: seems to be browser depended issue, it works perfect on chrome but messes up in ff/ie

Comment: @ChrisCannon Not sure what you mean by that, but I suppose an ideal solution would add or subtract 0, 24, or 48 pixels of margin/padding to the last element, so that the page ends exactly on a grid square.

Comment: @KishanThobhani I think the main issue is content-length, although I can see how text rendering in different browsers could affect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way we can add some sort of "smart" padding to the bottom
>   of these paragraphs to re-align the next elements to the grid?

I don't think there's a pure CSS fix, particularly when you take into account the fact that different browsers/operating systems might render the text with slightly different height.

The only other thing I can add to my answer is a JavaScript fix, which you don't want:

```
document.body.style.height = Math.round(document.body.offsetHeight/72)*72 + "px";
```

At least it's short.

Comment: I figured that JS was my only solution, but I always like to avoid resorting to JS if I can avoid it. I've seen some very clever CSS solutions in the past, so I thought I'd try my hand.

Comment: It's good to ask :) In this case though, I can't think of anything.